# Perl DBI: Return unique time stamp

Tags: sql, perl, dbi

I need a way to have the database return a unique time stamp (Format YYYYMMDD.HH:MM:SS) or something I can parse. My program has file names that come in and get renamed, I am trying to find a way to make sure I get no duplicate time stamps on a file and risk overwriting a file.  The database will only keep track of time record in YYYYMMDD.HH:MM:SS format.  If a file comes in and has a time that matches the database I need the database to return a new time stamp and update the database.

```
if( $fileName =~ m/^[a-z0-9]{3}[0-9]{5}\.[0-9]{5}\.([0-9]{8}\.[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})\.(.)*/ )
{
    $dttmstmp = $1;
}
else
{
    $current_time = Date->getDateTime();
    $dttmstmp = $current_time;
}

    my $databaseHandle = getDbConnection();
    my $tstamp_present = getDbTime ( $databaseHandle , $dttmstmp );

    if ($tstamp_present == 1)
    {
            sleep(1);   # sleep to change timestamp
            $dttmstmp = Date->getDateTime(); # Get new timestamp
            updateTimestamp ( $databaseHandle , $dttmstmp ); # Update database with new timestamp
    }
    else
    {
            updateTimestamp ( $databaseHandle , $dttmstmp ); # Update database with new timestamp
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Using a database for generating unique values doesn't sound like a good thing. A better way would be to use UUIDs. There are several modules on CPAN which can be used for this, e.g. [`Data::UUID`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data%3a%3aUUID).